# Anchoring two controls + centre

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to anchor two progress but I can't see a way to get the desired result.
I want the left progress bar to be anchored to the left, right bar to the right with the centre fixed (as imaged below)

[image]
(Bottom image shows resized form)

I've tried putting the controls on a docked panel with various anchor points but I cannot get the desired result, any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a `SplitContainer` and add a progress bar to each panel. Anchor the bars on both left and right and then ensure that the splitter is placed in the middle of the container. If the user shouldn't be allowed to subsequently move the splitter, set

`splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = false`

Comment: I thought that might be the case

Comment: Docking progress bars would be better than anchoring.

Comment: These two progress bars are parallel so cannot be docked while maintaining the layout.